# How to use GREP to list all of the lines in a file that do NOT have digits in them?

Tags: linux, grep

I have this file called sdata.txt with the following information:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Oct16 ?        00:01:15 /sbin/init
root                                            root
root        10     2  0 Oct16 ?        00:00:02 [migration/0]
root20
t90hch1    478   442  0 13:24 ?        00:00:00 sshd: t90hch1@pts/3
support

T90hch1    488   478  0 13:24 pts/3    00:00:00 -bash
root20     498     1  0 Oct16 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/mdadm --monitor --scan
root       730  1498  0 13:27 ?        00:00:00 sshd: z1746903 [priv]
z1J46903   763    48  0 13:27 ?        00:00:00 rooot: z1746903@pts/18
z4746903   764   763  0 13:27 pts/18   00:00:00 -bash
root      1492     1  0 Oct16 ?        00:00:32 /usr/sbin/testooooo
daemon    1493   408  1  0 Oct16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/atd -f
zY6A7846  1716 24089  0 13:35 pts/41   00:00:00 nano +183 Assign5.cpp
z1746903  1751   764  0 13:35 pts/18   00:00:00 nano
z1234567  1799   888                            bAsh
r78959j1   499                                  BUSH
```

I have to use grep in order to List the lines in this file that does NOT have digits in them. I also have another question in which I have to List all lines that have a 2 digit or 3 digit number that begins with a 4 and ends with an 8. If it is a 3 digit number, the middle digit must be 6 or greater. I'm really having trouble with this.

Comment: Sounds like someones regex homework...

Comment: For my own personal growth in Regex

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -v '[0-9]' sdata.txt`

... Just barely a regex :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, I also have one another question that involves: listing all lines that have a 2 digit or 3 digit number that begins with a 4 and end with an 8. If it is a 3 digit number, the middle digit must be 6 or greater. Just putting it out their in case anybody else wants to help lol

Answer (score 1):

> I have to use grep in order to List the lines in this file that does NOT have digits in them

Try `grep -v -e '[0-9]' t.txt`

> I also have another question in which I have to List all lines that have a 2 digit or 3 digit number that begins with a 4 and ends with an 8. If it is a 3 digit number, the middle digit must be 6 or greater

Try `grep  -e '\b4[6789]\?8\b' t.txt`

BTW, you could list what kind of trouble you had, so that others can help you to fix it and understand regex more.

Comment: Thank You, I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: `\d` matches just `d` in my grep... you'd have to use the `-P` option, at least in GNU grep.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for reminder, I just updated it to `[0-9]`